# How to margin element off screen and then translate it to the right with css?

Tags: html, css, css-position, transform, translate-animation

So I'm making this paragraph element to come from the left on page load, but im struggling. I can't push it out of the page while it waits for the other elements. If you know a better way of doing it than the below one, feel free to answer me.
Here is the code:

CSS

```
  .description {
      color: black;
      top: 60%;
      position: absolute;
      transform: translateX(137%);
      transition: 2s;
      -webkit-transition-delay: 500ms;
      -moz-transition-delay: 500ms;
      -o-transition-delay: 500ms;
      transition-delay: 500ms;
  }
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="bgimg-1">
        <div class="caption">
          <span class="border">AutoAFK</span>
        </div>
        <div class='outer'>
        <h1 class="description">The Best Anti-AFK Script</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

And [here](https://autoafk.netlify.app/) is the demo.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @keyframes for this.
Set the div you want to move to relative and it will move relative to the body or if it is wrapped into a another code it will move relative to that.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  animation: yourname 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes yourname {
  from {left: -200px;}
  to {left: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```